# Generating Random Prime Number

Tags: javascript, math

I know how to check whether a number is prime or not, but now I need to generate a random prime number. How can I do it by using JavaScript?

```
const isPrime = num => {
    for(let i = 2, s = Math.sqrt(num); i <= s; i++)
        if(num % i === 0) return false; 
    return num > 1;
}
```

Comment: what approaches have you tried?

Comment: Generate numbers until one of them is prime, generate all prime numbers for a given range and just generate a random index.

Comment: Hey, Andreas. Sorry I didn't understand you correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ggorlen pointed out, it's **more efficient** to find all prime numbers in the needed range beforehand and randomly return one of them.

In order to find all primes we should use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm. We also need a function to generate a random integer.

Finally, we can combine the two and create the desired function to generate a random *prime* number in the range **[min, max]**.

Here's my implementation:

```js
// AKA Sieve of Eratosthenes
const getPrimes = (min, max) => {
  const result = Array(max + 1)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => i);
  for (let i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(max + 1); i++) {
    for (let j = i ** 2; j < max + 1; j += i) delete result[j];
  }
  return Object.values(result.slice(Math.max(min, 2)));
};

const getRandNum = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

const getRandPrime = (min, max) => {
  const primes = getPrimes(min, max);
  return primes[getRandNum(0, primes.length - 1)];
};

// Example
console.log(getRandPrime(100, 1000));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Math.floor(Math.random()) to generate a random number. if we combine the two your code shuold look like that:

```
function rnd(min, max) => {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}
function getPrime(min, max){
   x = rnd(min, max)
   if(isPrime(x)) return x;
   else return getPrime(min, max);
}
```

and when you need a random prime number just call the function getPrime with 2 parameters: max value and min value.

**UPDATE**

you can do the same thing with a while loop, or create an array of prime numbers and generate a random index, and then take the prime number within the array.

Comment: Why is this the answer when your comment on my suggestion to generate random numbers until one of the is prime was: _"Isn't there a faster method?"_ ?

Comment: This seems like an inappropriate use of recursion. You could blow the call stack if you're unlucky, and it adds a lot of overhead even if you are lucky. A loop would be faster and safer. Also, instead of trying random numbers and stopping when you find a prime, you could generate primes in a range using a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and then pick from them. OP wants a fast method, but this doesn't guarantee a bound and uses OP's inefficient `isPrime` function.